# Python urlfetch returning bad data

Tags: python, pdf, urlfetch

**Note:** This question has been edited to reflect new information, including the title which used to be 'How to store a PDF in Amazon S3 with Python Boto library'.

I'm trying to save a PDF file using `urlfetch` (if the url was put into a browser, it would prompt a 'save as' dialog), but there's some kind of encoding issue.

There are lots of unknown characters showing up in the urlfetch result, as in:

```
urlfetch.fetch(url).text
```

The result has chars like this: `s�*��E����`
Whereas the same content in the actual file looks like this: `sÀ*ÿ<81>E®<80>Ùæ`

So this is presumably some sort of encoding issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it. The version of urlfetch I'm using is 1.0

For what it's worth, the PDF I've been testing with is here: http://www.revenue.ie/en/tax/it/forms/med1.pdf

Comment: Is the `pdf` broken if you download S3 directly?

Comment: If I download the PDF that I have put into S3, yes - it is broken.

Comment: I've just realised something that's important. I don't think this has anything to do with S3 or boto. After logging the contents of the result from urlfetch, it looks like the question mark chars are everywhere. So it's a problem with urlfetch... I'm going to update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to urllib instead of urlfetch e.g.

```
import urllib
result = urllib.urlopen(url)
```

...and everything seems to be fine.